# Notifications from favourite questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Wouldn't it better if we get notifications from the questions which we favourite ? It would help, by getting us notified about new answers to our favourite questions.

Or,

Is this feature already existing?

Comment: There is no such feature afaik. You could ask on meta if you like, as this is more of a SE wide community thing. Personally, and probably you already know, you can go to your profile by clicking on your icon on top of your screen and hit the favorites tab. There you can check them out.